# Tree traversal, reading the code

Tags: java, tree-traversal

I was looking up tree traversal and so far i had no problems understanding it, meaning pre-order, in-order, post-order. And the simple code like:

```
sub P(TreeNode)
Output(TreeNode.value)
If LeftPointer(TreeNode) != NULL Then
   P(TreeNode.LeftNode)
If RightPointer(TreeNode) != NULL Then
   P(TreeNode.RightNode)
end sub
```

i found a code that is longer and i got confused, what will be the output?

```
public class My {
 public static void print(Node n){
    if(n != null) {
       System.out.print(n.info +"");
       print(n.left);
       print(n.right);
    }
} 
 public static void print2(Node n){
    if(n != null) {           
       print2(n.left);
       System.out.print(n.info +"");
       print2(n.right);
    }
 }

 public static void print3(Node n){
    if(n != null) {           
       print3(n.left);
       print3(n.right);
       System.out.print(n.info +"");           
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
Tree t = new Tree();
   t.createTree();
   print(t.root);
   System.out.println();
   print2(t.root);
   System.out.println();
   print3(t.root);
}
}
```

and so just its easier for me to understand lets say that the input is 10,-10,12,8,21,34
whats will the output look like? because if i understood correctly then there are all 3 (pre-order, in-order, post-order).

tree will look like :

```
     10
-10     12
8  21  34
```

turns out this is exam in one of my schools and they have to give the answer one the paper, and this is all the information they get. No one tells them how the tree will look.

Comment: We can't see your Tree or Node class, so this could printed nothing... You should run your code in a debugger though

Comment: @cricket_007 Right, brainfart moment, sorry

Answer (score 0):

> And the simple code like:

There's pre order

> found a code that is longer and i got confused,

It's only longer because you have all the traversals

> the input is 10,-10,12,8,21,34  whats will the output look like?

No one can answer that without knowing what the actual tree looks like (that list of numbers could be output of any of the possible  traversals) . Once you have that information, run the code yourself (preferably stepping in a debugger) and see what it is

Comment: added how the tree should look one the paper, and some additional information that i found out about this example.

Comment: You seem to be confused how trees are built rather than traversed if you don't understand how that format was gotten

Comment: yeah might be the case, just recently started to look in to the tree traversals.